# troubles with c# interface and 3rd party class construction

Tags: c#, interface

I'm trying to interface with a DX class and getting construction errors.

```
public interface IDevice
{

}

class vJoystick : Joystick, IDevice
{   //ERROR Joystick does not take 0 parms...
    public vJoystick( Joystick joystick) {}
}

class vMouse : Mouse, IDevice
{   //ERROR Mouse does not take 0 parms...
    public vMouse( Mouse mouse ) { }
}

public class DeviceFactory
{
    public static IDevice Create( object device, DirectInput di, Guid g )
    {
        if ( device is Joystick ) return new vJoystick( new Joystick(di, g) );
        if ( device is Mouse )    return new vMouse( new Mouse ( di ));
        return new vJoystick( new Joystick( di, g ) );//defult
    }
}
```

See comment above. How can I make my classes pass the parameters for my class construction?

also is this a good usage, seem like an over kill?

```
Joystick device = ( Joystick ) DeviceFactory.Create( ( Joystick ) new Object(), directInput, deviceGuid );
```

Update: adding this per suggestion below.

```
  class vJoystick :  IDevice, Joystick
        {
            private  Joystick joystick;
            public vJoystick( DirectInput di, Guid g )
            {
                joystick = new Joystick(di,g);
            }
        }

        class vMouse : IDevice, Mouse
        {
            private  Mouse mouse;
            public vMouse( DirectInput di)
            {
                mouse = new Mouse( di);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an empty/default constructor?

Comment: You mean like  public vJoystick( ) {} ? this gives me the same error.

Comment: The error messages imply that the *base classes* - i.e. `Joystick` and `Mouse` - do not have an empty default constructor. Unless you specifically call a constructor of the base class with [`base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx), the compiler will automatically invoke the default constructor of the base class, or complain if there is none.

Comment: Also, your constructors are a bit strange, anyway. They *might* make sense as they are, but please rethink whether you really want to have your classes both inherit from (w.l.o.g.) `Joystick` *and* take a `Joystick` instance as a constructor argument.

Comment: You are confusing inheritance and encapsulation.  If you inherit Joystick then you need to call the base constructor explicitly since it doesn't have a default constructor.  If you encapsulate it then you need a private variable of type Joystick.  Passing a Joystick argument to the constructor only makes sense if you encapsulate it.

Comment: I believe I need encapsulation here. My biggest issue is being very new to c# and yet to learn terminology. Without knowing this well enough it makes research hard. So yes I need to somehow construct my Joystick and Mouse class with parameters but every example out there on Interfacing or Encapsulation does not have a 3rd party class constructor with multiple parameters. So its next to impossible to figure this out. I want my factory to return either a mouse or joystick to my agnostic device. I'm told I need to use encapsulation to do this but struggle with it.

Comment: I think I get what you mean now. See my edit to the above OP. Is that more of an encapsulation.

Comment: If I did get that right my next question is how to use it? When I do a <<IDevice device =  DeviceFactory.Create( ( Joystick ) new Object(), directInput, deviceGuid );>> I get myself a new device but no joystick members.So any device.Dothis() reports a missing definition. So how do I inherit with encapsulation? Or am I way off here.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need inheritance (and I'm not quite convinced that is the case), try this:

```
public interface IDevice
{

}

class vJoystick : Joystick, IDevice
{
    public vJoystick(DirectInput di, Guid g) : base(di, g) {}
}

class vMouse : Mouse, IDevice
{
    public vMouse( DirectInput di ) : base(di) { }
}

public class DeviceFactory
{
    public static IDevice Create( object device, DirectInput di, Guid g )
    {
        if ( device is Joystick ) return new vJoystick(di, g);
        if ( device is Mouse )    return new vMouse(di);
        return new vJoystick(di, g);//defult
    }
}
```

Basically, since you're deriving `vJoystick` from `Joystick`, the `base(di, g)` effectively does the same thing as `new vJoystick(di, g)`. You can't create an instance of a derived type from the base type in C# (ie. extend it).

Also, if you want to use DX from .NET, I'd suggest using a working managed wrapper for .NET instead, for example SlimDX or SharpDX. You're going to save a lot of time, and unless you know extremely well what you're doing, it's going to improve your performance significantly as well. Not to mention reduce the incidence of memory leaks and other fun stuff :)

Comment: I'm using SharpDx, if that helps. Ill try this code and see if it sheds any light for me.

Comment: using the code above didnt work as you predicted. Failed after using IDevice device =  DeviceFactory.Create( ( Mouse ) new Object(), directInput ); Code works but my new IDevice does not have the inherited members.

Comment: @SeanGreen Well, in your code, `IDevice` has no members. `vJoystick` is implementing (*not* inheriting) the `IDevice` interface, ie. if you have an `IDevice` variable which contains a reference to a `vJoystick`, it will call the methods on `vJoystick`. However, the method has to be defined in the `IDevice` interface in the first place. The interface will not "grow" based on what specific instance you feed it. Why would you expect anything else? What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you should take a look at what interfaces are for.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm going down the wrong path yet again here. I need IDevice to take on many meanings ( AKA polymorphism ). So that I can define a device as IDevice at the top class level and allow it to be constructed in to one of 3 forums ( Joystick, Mouse, Keyboard ). Also the new form must be inherited from its Class so that I have its member accessible. How is that handled in c#?

Comment: @SeanGreen It seems so. The `IDevice` value can have different meanings, but you have to explicitly cast it to eg. `vJoystick` to get the desired functionality. If you have some common functionality over all the devices, you can simply define them in the `IDevice` interface and implement them in the various `vXXX` classes. Then you can directly call the methods on `IDevice` references and that's it. What language are you familiar with that treats interfaces the way you expect them?

Comment: Just for clarification I need my result from IDevice to inherit from SharPDX. I see that was not made clear to you at first. When I said " IDevice does not have the inherited members" I meant that I cant call any SharpDx methods.

Comment: @SeanGreen Interfaces don't inherit. They are a description of a contract. You can only access members defined in this contract (the interface definition), unless you cast the value to a more specific type. Really, you should read up on how interfaces work, along with the OOP principles etc.

Comment: ok, so your saying just recast as needed? Here is a c++ example of what I want in c# http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_248.html

Comment: @SeanGreen If that's what you need, sure. Of course, in that case, you don't need the interface at all - just return `object` - that's the base type of the whole .NET type system. Obviously, this is not really such a good idea :) Or use a common class both of the devices inherit from. Or create a wrapper, that can handle both possible devices. There's tons of options. Really, read up just a bit on interfaces and classes and stuff, object oriented programming etc. Even just the basics will get you quite far. It's not C# specific, all "object" languages have the same principles, with some diffs.

Comment: @SeanGreen As for the link. First, don't learn C# from C++ tutorials - that's generally a bad idea. Second, you can do that in C#, sure. The part where you're messing this up is that you don't have the common `Shape` base class. If the two devices don't have a common contract you can use for both, there's little point in making them implement the same (empty) interface. In that case, the interface is pretty much just a marker (useful, but not what you want). Still, in both cases, you most likely want to encapsulate the device, not inherit from it.

Comment: I think my biggest hurtle here is that I'm using a 3rd party class or this would be easier for me. Though the more I think of it, any way I go, re casting is really what I want here. Even though it is bad practices...

Comment: @SeanGreen Casting is *not* a bad practice inherently. And .NET protects you - you *can't* cast a `Mouse` to `Joystick` the way you can in C++. If you don't know the correct type in advance, you can use the `as` keyword which returns null if the cast is invalid, or `is` which returns a boolean value ("is the device a mouse?").

Comment: Ok, you said "You can't cast a Mouse to Joystick" ? but that is exactly what I need to do. The Mouse and the Joystick share the same member names, but the returned info will be different ( yet in the same form ).  For example is I do a   device.GetCurrentState( ref deviceState );  Depending on what device is I will get value that correspond to it. So i need to cast to a keyboard to get keyboard info. If I leave it as a Joystick I still can get the info I need but talking in joystick talk if you will. Buttons, analogs, etc not keys and keyStates.

Comment: @SeanGreen But `Mouse` is not a `Joystick`. The fact that they have a method of the same *name* doesn't mean anything. In fact, the two `GetCurrentState` methods have a different signature - they return different types as the device state. You have to build your own abstractions on top of the devices, not expect them to magically appear on their own :)

Comment: So really if I wanted to "convert" one to the next this should be done within ?SharpDX, or I would need to implement 3 classes and use them accordingly?

Comment: Thx for all the help, best option was to just let my class handle all 3 types (until I understand better ) but its ugly as h4ll.         public void deleteDevice()
        {
            if ( jDevice != null)  jDevice.Dispose() ;      
            if ( mDevice != null)  mDevice.Dispose() ;      
            if ( kDevice != null)  kDevice.Dispose() ;      

        }

Comment: @SeanGreen In the case of `Dispose`, this is unnecessary. All of the devices also implement the interface `IDisposable`, so you can just do `((IDisposable)device).Dispose();`.

Comment: But I no longer have device. Now I have to keep track of all 3 devices. In c++ there were pointers that could be used to point to an instance but c# does not work directly with memory that I know of.

Comment: @SeanGreen You can assign any type to a variable of any of its base types or interfaces. Since all of the various devices implement `IDisposable`, you can have a field of type `IDisposable`, and assign all the different device types to that one - and call `Dispose()` on that just fine. You should really read up on some good practices, the C++ thing you mentioned is extremely bad practice in C++ as well. Not to mention that C++ doesn't work "directly" with memory either, that's just an illusion. As for unsafe, pointers in C++ are also unsafe. You can do a lot of dangerous operations with them.

Comment: You're trying to solve a simple OOP problem with hacks, that's not the way to go. In any case, this discussion is no longer in any way related to the question, so you should just accept this answer and perhaps field another question (although in this case, it's better fit for review / programmers, rather than stack overflow).